# How to find a specific number from a user set upperbound and lowerbound in java

Tags: java, module, nested-loops

The purpose of my code is to determine the number of times the number `3` appears between a range of numbers, the lower and upper bounds determined by the user.

So far, I can check if the number `3` is in the ten's place my using the modulus. But I am having trouble figuring out if a `3` resides in the hundreds, thousandths, etc. I know I need to use a nested loop, but I can't quite figure out how to code it.

Here is my code so far.

```java
public class JavaThree {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int count = 0;
        int num;

        System.out.print("Enter lower end: ");
        int lowerEnd = IO.readInt();

        System.out.print("Enter upper end: ");
        int upperEnd = IO.readInt();

        if (lowerEnd > upperEnd) {
            IO.reportBadInput();
            return;
        } else {
            for(num = lowerEnd; num <= upperEnd; num++) {
                if(num % 10 == 3) {
                    count = count + 1;
                } else {
                    count = count;
                }
            }
        }

        IO.outputIntAnswer(count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is proper for loop for your task:

```
    for(num = lowerEnd; num <= upperEnd; num++)
    {
        int nNum = num;
        while (nNum > 0)
        {
            if( (nNum % 10) == 3)
                count = count + 1;
            nNum = nNum / 10;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, although not as efficient as the solution proposed [@Ilya Bursov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864275/ilya-bursov) is to convert the number to a string and count the appearences of the char `'3'`:

```
int threeCount = 0;
for (int num = lowerEnd; num < upperEnd; num++) { 
    String strNumber = String.valueOf(num);
    for (int i = 0; i < strNumber.length(); i++) {
        if (strNumber.charAt(i) == '3') { 
            threeCount++;
        }
    }
}
```